# Python 2.6, проблемы с кодировками

Tags: кодировка, python-2.x

Есть код:

```
# -*- coding: cp1251 -*-

import json


a = {'абв': 123}
print(a)

with open(r'<myfile>', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(a, f, encoding='cp1251')


with open(r'<myfile>', 'r') as f:
    tree = json.load(f, encoding='cp1251')

print(tree)
```

В выводе вижу:

```
{'\xe0\xe1\xe2': 123}
{u'\u0430\u0431\u0432': 123}
```

Дефолтная кодировка моей системы (Win) это cp1251.
Вторая строка совпадает с тем, что записалось в файл. Подскажите пожалуйста, как исправить кодировку?

Comment: JSON не способен хранить байтовые строки, он способен хранить только юникод. Поэтому начать стоит с переделывания программы так, чтобы перестать пытаться пихать байтовые строки в JSON

Comment: (и очень странно использовать Python 2.6 в 2024 году)

Comment: согласен, максимально странно, окружение не мое: использую окружение стороннего софта